# Change this from resetting every month to every day?

Tags: php, mysql

I've the following code which counts the number of messages sent every month. Can this be changed to daily? I've tried a number of alterations but they haven't been successful. Any suggestions? Thank you so much in advance! I'm fairly new to PHP/MySQL. Also, I know the current MySQL query is deprecated!:

```
$vmYear = date("Y"); 
$vmMonth = date("m"); 

$vmfromdate = mktime(0,0,0,$vmMonth,"1",$vmYear); 
$vmtodate = mktime(0,0,0,$vmMonth,"31",$vmYear); 

$verifmessagespermonth = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM messages WHERE msg_from = '$session_memberid' AND ( time BETWEEN '$vmfromdate' AND '$vmtodate' )"); 
$nummessagesthismonth = mysql_num_rows($verifmessagespermonth); 
} else { 
$nummessagesthismonth = 0; 
}
```

Comment: What is the table schema?

Answer (score 2):

Keeping int in the same structure as you have, by adding the day (provided that you store date only). If you store date+time, you may need to change the `0,0,0` from `$vmtodate` to `23,59,59`

```
$vmYear = date("Y"); 
$vmMonth = date("m");
$vmDay = date("d");

$vmfromdate = mktime(0,0,0,$vmMonth,$vmDay,$vmYear); 
$vmtodate = mktime(0,0,0,$vmMonth,$vmDay,$vmYear);
```

This still allows you to make other ranges if you like

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly the requirements you can use this query:

```
SELECT 
  ID 
FROM 
  messages 
WHERE 
  msg_from = '$session_memberid' 
  AND time BETWEEN 
     DATE_FORMAT(NOW() , '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00' ) 
     AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW() , '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59' )
```